# In PHP, how can I just create the conn to database once and use it many times from JavaScript through Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ajax, database

I use Ajax to request remote PHP file for database accessing. Every time I request, the conn will be re-created. How can I just create it once and use it many times?

The PHP file:

db.php

```
<?php
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db1', 'webuser', 'secret');

$query = 'SELECT * FROM `table1`';

$stmt = $conn->query($query);

echo $stmt->fetchAll();
?>
```

The JavaScript File (in Angular):

user.js

```
$http.get('localhost')
    .success(function (data) {
        // to process the data...
    });
```

Can I share the conn object to all the requests? How can I preserve the conn object? I think the re-creating in every time is a waste of resource.

Comment: Unless you have an insanely busy site, your current method will have very little impact.

Comment: Thank you! Are there any ways to preserve the conn object for the next coming Ajax request?

Comment: You're already leaving the connection open for the entirety of the running of the script on any given all. But opening a new connection each time for each request is actually the more desirable behavior. The connection terminates automatically when the script has run its course.

Comment: OK, thank you very much!

Comment: This is how PHP works. The script runs on request. This will be totally different in Node, this is one of the reasons why server side JS can be more efficient than PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has got answers. Please refer to the above comments. In PHP, it's not easy and not necessary to do so.